# < any , < all gives the same results in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

when I use this query

```
mysql> select movieid from rating where stars < any (select stars from rating where 

movieid=103);
```

the output is as below

```
movieid 

 101 
 108    
 104
```

when I execute the below query, the results seems to be the same. Why is that?

```
> mysql> select movieid,stars from rating where stars <all (select stars
> from rating where movieid=103);

+---------+-------+
| movieid | stars |
+---------+-------+
|     101 |     2 |
|     108 |     2 |
|     104 |     2 |
+---------+-------+
```

shouldn't the all keyword give back the results which are **less than** to the stars value 2? which in this case would be an empty set.

here is a capture

[image]

Comment: it is mysql.. the prompt above shows it

Comment: well i just copied from the command prompt.sorry about that. anyway does this result has to do anything with correlated queries?

Comment: I don't get the same results as you from the supplied data - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b872/3

Comment: where are the results of the queries? there are only two tables

Comment: Scroll down - there are three result sets; the first shows all the records in the table, the second shows 4 results for the `any` query, the third shows no results for the `all` query - which is what we would expect, but not what you have reported.

Comment: yeah it is different from mine. why does that happen? i'm using mysql 5.5

Comment: The SQLFiddle is also using MySQL 5.5, but the query returns the same results with 5.1.61 and 5.6.6 m9 too.

Comment: movieid and reviewerid are foreign keys from two other tables. does that have to do something with the result i am getting?

Comment: Not if the queries and data match what is in your post.

Comment: check the screen capture above

Comment: The data in the capture is different from the original data, you have 3 stars for 103 for both (as opposed to 3 and 2)

Comment: Well that explains the confusion any(3) and all(3) are the same thing :)

Comment: oh god.. Thanks alot... I have been careless all this time.

Comment: ...as the Dalek said, climbing off the dustbin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the capture is different from the data you posted earlier, you have 3 stars for both rows with movieid = 103 (as opposed to 3 and 2)

**As for the first data you provided:**

First query with `any' is equivalent to:

```
select movieid from rating where stars < 2 OR stars < 3
```

and the result is:

```
101
103
108
104
```

The second query is equivalent to:

```
select movieid from rating where stars < 2 AND stars < 3
```

and the result is an empty set.

**For the screen capture data:**

Both queries are equivalent to:

```
select movieid from rating where stars < 3
```

and the result is:

```
101
108
104
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but if i were writing this I would have done something like:

```
/* is this what you want by "any" */
select movieid,stars from rating where stars < (select max(stars) from rating where movieid=103);

/* is this what you want by "all" */
select movieid,stars from rating where stars < (select min(stars) from rating where movieid=103);
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfa4e0/2)